# How To Create A Link In Jquery

Tags: jquery

The result of this code does not display as a link rather it displays the HTML. How do I fix this?

```
for(t = 0; t < jobs.length; ++t) {
    $('.space').val('<a href="http://localhost:53112/category/c?id=' + jobs[t].Id + '">' + jobs[t].Occupation + ' ' + jobs[t].Years + '</a>');
}
```

Comment: If I do html nothing displays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [jQuery.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/), if you are adding multiple links. [jQuery.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) will keep overwriting the previous link.

```
for(var t = 0; t < jobs.length; ++t) {
    var href = 'http://localhost:53112/category/c?id=' + jobs[t].Id;
    var text = jobs[t].Occupation + ' ' + jobs[t].Years;
    $('.space').append($('<a/>').attr('href', href).text(text));
}
```

Comment: append doesn't seem to be working? can I append to an input box?

Comment: From jQuery's website: `Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements`.

Comment: The `<input/>` element may not have a close tag, which means it may not contain HTML. - https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/single-page.html#restrictions-on-content-models-and-on-attribute-values

Comment: This is the input box <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg space" />

Comment: @N.Sch, yes that is an `<input/>` element. Please see my response: you cannot add HTML to it.

Comment: Thank You! So what should I change it to?

Comment: Any number of elements would do. Trying using a `<div/>` or a `<p/>`. Basically, if the element is not self-closing, you can use it to contain HTML.

Comment: Thank You so much for taking the time to explain this to me!